# Retrofit response not getting

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

**Hi, I'm using retrofit for JSON parsing.I got 200 response code, but I didn't get any proper response to my ArrayList. I only get the response to "status" field.Other Fields are getting null. Please Help me.JSON data are given below Thank you :)**

//json parsing method

```
     private void load() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(client)


        Apiinterface request = retrofit.create(Apiinterface.class);
        Call<MyPojo> call = request.newsget(new Newslist_Post("en",0));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MyPojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyPojo> call, Response<MyPojo> response{
                try {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        Log.d("act", "onResponse - Status : " +response.code());
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                       TypeAdapter<MyPojo>adapter=gson.getAdapter(MyPojo.class);
                        try {
                            if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    MyPojo news_model = response.body();

                   // data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(news_model.getNews()));
                    status=news_model.isStatus();
                    count=news_model.getCount();
                    data=news_model.getNews();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyPojo> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Check your network",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              //Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
       });}
```

ModelClass

These model classes are used to parse the JSON, in this model class list get second model class contents

```
 public class MyPojo{
 @SerializedName("status")
 private boolean status;
 @SerializedName("count")
 private int count;
 @SerializedName("news")
 private List<News>news;
 public int getCount() {
    return count;
 }
 public List<News> getNews() {
    return news;
 }
 public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
 }
```

Second ModelClass

In this model class contains news data, this news data get in the first model class list.

```
 public class News

 {

 private String news_id;

 private String newss_description;

 private String newss_title;

 private String news_image;

  private String lang;

 public String getNews_id ()
 {
    return news_id;
 }

 public String getNewss_description ()
  {
    return newss_description;
  }

public String getNewss_title ()
{
    return newss_title;
}
public String getNews_image ()
{
    return news_image;
}
public String getLang ()
{
    return lang;
}
}



 //JSON


       {
"status": true,
"count": 2,
"news": [
    {
        "news_id": "2",
        "news_image": "5fc2eaf170e6fc8ba6aa3974ce0c2e11.jpg",
        "newss_title": "new 1",
        "newss_description": "test news",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    {
        "news_id": "1",
        "news_image": "31e3650272d006d24ac6c5fd580cace0.jpg",
        "newss_title": "cooking class with tanya in the name of healthy",
        "newss_description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        "lang": "en"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: the names in your POJO @SerializedName must be the same in your JSON response

Answer (score 0):

SerializedName and Expose is missing for news model item

```
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
```

Change your News.class like this.

```
public class News {
    @SerializedName("news_id")
    @Expose
    private String news_id;
    @SerializedName("newss_description")
    @Expose
    private String newss_description;

    @SerializedName("newss_title")
    @Expose
    private String newss_title;

    @SerializedName("news_image")
    @Expose
    private String news_image;

    @SerializedName("lang")
    @Expose
    private String lang;

    public String getNews_id() {
        return news_id;
    }

    public String getNewss_description() {
        return newss_description;
    }

    public String getNewss_title() {
        return newss_title;
    }

    public String getNews_image() {
        return news_image;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your MyPojo and News class like below

```html
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;
@SerializedName("count")
@Expose
private Integer count;
@SerializedName("news")
@Expose
private List<News> news = null;

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

public Integer getCount() {
return count;
}

public void setCount(Integer count) {
this.count = count;
}

public List<News> getNews() {
return news;
}

public void setNews(List<News> news) {
this.news = news;
}

}

// News class

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class News {

@SerializedName("news_id")
@Expose
private String newsId;
@SerializedName("news_image")
@Expose
private String newsImage;
@SerializedName("newss_title")
@Expose
private String newssTitle;
@SerializedName("newss_description")
@Expose
private String newssDescription;
@SerializedName("lang")
@Expose
private String lang;

public String getNewsId() {
return newsId;
}

public void setNewsId(String newsId) {
this.newsId = newsId;
}

public String getNewsImage() {
return newsImage;
}

public void setNewsImage(String newsImage) {
this.newsImage = newsImage;
}

public String getNewssTitle() {
return newssTitle;
}

public void setNewssTitle(String newssTitle) {
this.newssTitle = newssTitle;
}

public String getNewssDescription() {
return newssDescription;
}

public void setNewssDescription(String newssDescription) {
this.newssDescription = newssDescription;
}

public String getLang() {
return lang;
}

public void setLang(String lang) {
this.lang = lang;
}

}
```